# google mobile vision qr reader read possible raw data from damaged qr code

Tags: android, computer-vision, qr-code

I have very specific kind of a barcodes.let's assume a business card QR code. but the quality of QR is not good in some cards. how every 80% of the text is a constant and same in every QR.

[image]

for example

```
card 1  "this is the same text in every QR H123"
card 2  "this is the same text in every QR M936"
```

and I know the error code, mask and code type information.

```
public class BarcodeReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BarcodeReaderFragment.BarcodeReaderListener {
          ...
    }
```

what I want is to recover the code in damaged QR for that I need to get raw data with unread data.so I can do some processing and try to read the code .this seems possible with zxing library as I can edit the library code.but is it possible in mobile vision API ? or is there any way to override some function

Comment: Barcodes are pretty standardized and the codewords within the barcode have a level of error correction. If the source image is so badly damaged/altered that a stock decoder can't extract the data, you'll have to write/modify a library like ZXing or pre-process the image for Mobile Vision to read it.

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks for the information.so, in that case, I have to parallelly scan from zxing and mobile vision because mobile vision doesn't provide methods to detect broken QR .is it possible to modify code of mobile vision API internal codes

Comment: Or make it so that ZXing treats your problematic QR code as a different barcode under the hood. If this is a regular thing where the barcode gets damaged, you should recommend to your client to use a higher level of error correction or a different barcode. If a small one time batch I wouldn't be above scanning all of them and using a photo editor to make it readable QR code. Good luck.

Comment: If it's damaged like your example image you're going to have a tricky time even finding the QR code without the positioning and alignment squares.

Comment: @RyanMentley actually it's not that damaged .i replaced the image with more accurate one .